# What is the best practice for querying data with Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

On Spark 2.0.0, if I had a database where I am constantly using a table A to do joins with other tables, should I persist my table A and do joins this way? Or should I use the Spark SQL approach of specifying the query of joining A and B, A and C, etc?

And if I want to query a table Z multiple times using where conditional i.e

```
SELECT * FROM Z where z_id = '1'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Z where z_id = '2'
```

Should I use Spark SQL and explicitly it query for it, or query for the table and act on the table RDD?

Comment: If you use a rdd or a dataframe more than once, I would say it is always good to use persist(). You should try before asking !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple things. If the filter will be used multiple times , please use as below.

```
**df=sqlContext.sql('''select * from Z ''')
df.registerTempTable('Z_temp') 
sqlContext.cacheTable('Z_temp')**
```

Persit with out any parameter and cache saves/stores data in memory.

Make sure you use spark.sql.parquet.filter pushdown=True if you are using multiple filter from the table.